# Calculation of the limit for a composite function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let's assume that we have a composite function $g(f(x))$, which is not defined at $f(x)=0$. We know that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =0$. Further, we know that $\lim_{f(x) \to 0}g(f(x))=L $. $f(x)$ is a well behaving, continuous function; $g(y)$ is similar, only it is just not defined at $y=f(x)=0$.

I wonder that if it is possible to show that it is $\lim_{x \to 0}g(f(x))  = L$. I don't know exactly whether it is even possible to evaluate a limit with a dependent ($f(x)$ here, with $\lim_{f(x) \to 0}g(f(x))=L$) variable, but it looks like so intuitive that I thought it can be shown in a rigorous way.

Here is what I have tried so far:

First, we fix $\epsilon > 0$; we know that there is a $\delta$ such that it is $|g(f(x))-L| < \epsilon$, whenever $0<|f(x)|<\delta$. We pick such a $\delta$. Now I must be able to show that for that $\delta$, there are $x$ values such that $0 < |x| < \delta' \implies 0<|f(x)| <\delta$ . Since we know $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=0$, due to the definition of this limit, such a $\delta'$ always exists.

Is my proof valid? If not, how this problem can be proven or disproven? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the function $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$. Since $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{y \to 0} g(y) = L \in \mathbb{R}$, you can extend $g$ to a continuous function $\overline{g}$ :

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \; \overline{g}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\[2mm]
L & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\end{cases}.
$$

The function $\overline{g}$ is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Note that :

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \big( g \circ f \big)(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \big( \overline{g} \circ f \big)(x). $$

Since $g \circ f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous at $0$ and :

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \big( \overline{g} \circ f \big)(x) = \overline{g}\big( f(0) \big) = \overline{g}(0) = L. $$

As a consequence, $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \big( g \circ f \big)(x) = L$.

Comment: After defining $\overline{g}$ you said that $\lim_{x \to 0}(g \circ f)(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}(\overline{g} \circ f)(x)$. How do we see that? I did not get that part.

Comment: Secondly, what about my proof with $\epsilon-\delta$ approach? Can we say that it is correct?

Comment: For your 1st comment : you just need to observe that : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{\ast}, \; \big( \overline{g} \circ f \big)(x) = \big( g \circ f \big)(x)$. For your 2nd comment : it would be more correct to write: there exist $\delta > 0$ such that : $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \; \big( \, \vert y \vert \leq \delta \, \big) \, \Rightarrow \, \big( \vert g(y) - L \vert \leq \varepsilon \, \big)$. Then, as you said, you need to prove there exist $\delta' > 0$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert \leq \delta$ for all $x$ such that $\vert x \vert \leq \delta'$. It follows from the continuity of $f$ at $0$.